# Dereferencing struct(to get a struct member) does not return me another struct

Tags: c

I have a struct called child that holds another struct called Parent in it. I de-reference the child struct and access the int data member of it but all I'm receiving is garbage/undefined results. I know I can just access the struct from the child class pointer with dayum->prnt however I'm doing this because I want to learn about C more in depth. I'm a beginner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Parent
{
        int mangojuice;
};

struct Child
{
        struct Parent *prnt;
        int childtea;
};

void initChild(struct Child *chile)
{

        chile->prnt = (struct Parent*)malloc(sizeof(struct Parent));
        chile->childtea = 66;
        chile->prnt->mangojuice = 100;
}

int main()
{
        struct Child grass;
        struct Child* dayum = &grass;
        initChild(dayum); 
        printf("YEEYE %d", ((struct Parent*)(dayum))->mangojuice);
}
```

As far as I know, changing the pointer type to the struct type I should be able to reference the struct as my Parent struct is in the first of the struct. What is the problem?

Comment: Your cast is wrong. `dayum` is a pointer and the first member of the `Child` struct is also a pointer. So you'd have to cast to a `struct Parent**` (and adjust the dereferencing accordingly)

Comment: @UnholySheep thanks for your pointer(wasn't mean to be a pun) I've managed to find a solution however I just want to confirm that the reasoning is thorough.        printf("YEEYE %d", (*((struct Parent**)(dayum)))->mangojuice);
The dayum pointer is converted to struct Parent **pointer however it still points to the same address. The purpose behind the conversion to  struct Parent** pointer is that it allows it to be *dereferenced* properly into the struct pointer member. Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

This line is incorrect:

```
printf("YEEYE %d", ((struct Parent*)(dayum))->mangojuice);   // WRONG
```

It should be:

```
printf("YEEYE %d", dayum->prnt->mangojuice);
```

`dayum` is of type `struct Child*`, and therefore `dayum->prnt` accesses it's `prnt` member. This member is itself of type `struct Parent *`, and therefore `dayum->prnt->mangojuice` will access the `mangojuice` member of the inner struct. No cast is needed.